# Third Party Transit Insurance - Aussie Registered Car Travelling Via Singapore, Malaysia Into Thailand

Tags: driving, automobiles, insurance, singapore

I am planning a one-way trip with my private Aussie registered car shipped to Singapore, then transiting Singapore, Malaysia then imported into Thailand. 
 The overland trip by car is something I want to do, visiting relatives in KL along the way.
Hence why I'm not thinking of shipping the cat directly to Thailand.

The [LTA in Singapore](http://www.lta.gov.sg/content/ltaweb/en/roads-and-motoring/driving-in-and-out-of-singapore/foreign-registered-vehicles.html) states that, for cars entering Singapore, a vehicle insurance certificate issued by a Singapore-based insurance company is required.

I have been unable to find short-term third party only transit insurance for the Asian leg of this trip. Can anyone assist with information?

Comment: Is there a reason you are shipping it to Singapore, then driving the rest of the way, rather than shipping to Thailand directly?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you add a link to the relevant authority you are quoting? Just for future reference. :)

Comment: Thank you Tom for your response. The overland trip by car is something I want to do, visiting relatives in KL along the way.
Here is the link to the relevant authority I quoted (LTA Singapore)
http://www.lta.gov.sg/content/ltaweb/en/roads-and-motoring/driving-in-and-out-of-singapore/foreign-registered-vehicles.html

Answer (score 1):

Since your car is entering Singapore directly via ship, I would *strongly* recommend **you contact the company you're using to ship the car over**: they will likely already have arranged this, or at the very least can point you in the right direction.

The one complication is that you're effectively only trans-shipping your car *through* Singapore, since you're heading straight to Malaysia.  Have you considered having your car shipped to Malaysia (eg. Tanjung Pelapas, a major port right across the border) and then daytripping from there, or better yet, leaving the car in Malaysia and just visiting by public transport?  I suspect this would be considerably cheaper and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Every Border i have ever crossed in a car has had an insurance broker at the border.  You can usually buy 7, 14 or 30 days insurance and it costs next to nothing.

I must have done 30 border crossing but i have never driven a foreign car in Singapore.